# Access $content values in Drupal theme creation

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, themes

I'm trying to create a bespoke Drupal theme. I have created a content type and have a template for that specific template type:

```
node--event.tpl.php
```

This loads fine and I can dump the `$content` variable and see it's content. What I'm struggling with however is getting individual elements from the `$content` array and outputting them on the page in the format I want. For example:

```
echo render($content['field_date']);
```

outputs:

```
Date:
25th December 2014...
```

I don't want the label however, just the date itself. Yet if I try to `var_dump($content['field_date']);` it outputs the whole `$content` array.

I've looked at the docs here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7

But they don't go into much detail. So if anyone could give me any pointer on how to truly access the individual values in the `$content` array that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Goto `Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » Your content type » Manage Display` and you can see lable drop down and select `hidden` option. i hope it will be work for you.

Comment: Kind of works... gets rid of the labels but is still wrapped with divs.

Comment: Not sure but you need to select format as `plain` from your `manage display`.

Comment: Use `strip_tags()` to get rid of the divs.

Comment: I've found I can directly access the `$variables` variable for the values I need to be more specific with.

Comment: @diggersworld Install (then configure) [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to print only the field value. 
When you debug the field first try to print the array keys of $content[…] and then work your way through to get to the field value.